# XML parsing Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I have XML-request from web service. It looks like this. So, how can I get orderId value? I never work with XML in Java.

```
<order1s uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order">
<order1 uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/"> 
<customer uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/customer/">
<name/>
<passengerId>123</passengerId>
<phone/>
<rating>0.0</rating>
<restToken>
985y3289y5v43535v032m0v3v0b0jcrmjsa9w20m02umc3
</restToken>
<surname/>
</customer>
<offerCollection uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/offerCollection/"/>
<orderId>401</orderId>
<orderWaypointsCollection uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/orderWaypointsCollection/">
<orderWaypoints uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/orderWaypointsCollection/null/">
<isStartPoint>true</isStartPoint>
<latitude>50.505463</latitude>
<longitude>30.44121</longitude>
<norder uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/orderWaypointsCollection/null/norder/"/>
</orderWaypoints>
<orderWaypoints uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/orderWaypointsCollection/null/">
<isStartPoint>false</isStartPoint>
<latitude>50.4501</latitude>
<longitude>30.5234</longitude>
<norder uri="http://mywebsite/rest/create_order/401/orderWaypointsCollection/null/norder/"/>
</orderWaypoints>
</orderWaypointsCollection>
<status>1</status>
<toDate>19/05/2011 17:49:12</toDate>
<toNow>true</toNow>
</order1>
</order1s>
```

Comment: I have edited your XML to remove the location of your website, and changed the security token.  I was worried it might allow a hacker to submit malicious requests to your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [XPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html):

It will be something like:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "orderId";
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(xmlInputStreamOrReaderOrSomethingElse). 
String id = (String) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Updated:

expression must be `"//orderId"`: [example](http://pastebin.com/5h7SfQtN)

Comment: @Dima Svinarenko: yes, sorry. It should be `String expression = "//orderId";` I check on [this](http://pastebin.com/5h7SfQtN) example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse it using the facilities built into the platform, you can use a SAX [`DefaultHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html).  There are a bunch of answers here that point to tutorials.

If you just need the `orderId` value and none of the other values, then I would suggest just using a regular expression like:

```
<orderId>(\d+)<\/orderId>
```