# How to parse XML from assets?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have an XML file in my assets with such data

```
<mods day="30" month="8" year="2012">
        <mod id="1" name="1a">Hello123</mod>
        <mod id="2" name="2a">Hello123</mod>
        <mod id="3" name="3a">Hello123</mod>
    </mods>

<mods day="31" month="8" year="2012">
        <mod id="1" name="1a">Hello123</mod>
        <mod id="2" name="2a">Hello123</mod>
        <mod id="3" name="3a">Hello123</mod>
    </mods>
```

and I need to find a certain "mod" parameter by inputting day, month, year and id.

here's how far I got.

```
c.setTime(new Date());

String y = sdy.format(c.getTime());
String m = sdm.format(c.getTime());
String d = sdd.format(c.getTime());


InputStream istr = this.getAssets().open("mods.xml");
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(); 
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
XmlPullParser xrp;
xrp = factory.newPullParser();
xrp.setInput(istr, "UTF-8");  

// not sure what to do next...
```

If I got it right, now I need to somehow query this xrp with my needed parameters, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this topic helps you: [XML parsing Java (Android)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062454/xml-parsing-java-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the XML as an XML resource in `res/xml/`, not in `assets/`, it will parse 10x faster, courtesy of the optimizations in place for XML resources. Hence, I recommend using XML resources instead of XML in assets. You can see this CommonsWare [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/XML/) he uses the XMLPullParser to parse the xml resource.

Comment: Also as an addition to this answer: if you're targeting devices with API >= 8, it's easier to use [XPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)